# Google App Engine (Python), OAuth2, Service Accounts, User Delegation, Youtube Service

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube, oauth-2.0

I'm using the [Youtube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), along with the [Python client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) on Google App Engine.

Here is a simple snippet of code that fails:

```
kwargs = {'prn' : google_oauth_user_email}
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(google_oauth_email, google_oauth_key, scope=YOUTUBE_SCOPE, **kwargs)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, http=http)
request = youtube.channels().list(part="snippet", id="25")
response = request.execute(http=http)
```

which results in:

```
Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "access_denied"
}
```

If I remove the kwargs so as not to delegate user access, this request works fine. The Service Account is registered against the same user account to which delegation is being requested.

My ultimate goal is to upload videos (on behalf of that user) using the Server-to-Server two-legged OAuth2 flow.

Can anybody explain to me why delegation to the same user account as that which the Service Account is already registered fails, and how I might be able to allow it?

Comment: Have you tried using `sub` instead of `prn`?